# CのソースコードをVisual Studio Expressを利用してコンパイル・実行したい

Tags: c, visual-studio

アルゴリズムとデータ構造という書籍を買い、下記よりC/C++のソースコードをダウンロードしました。
http://www.sbcr.jp/books/img/takarabako/

書籍には、VS Expressを用いたコンパイル＆実行方法が載っているのですが、上手くいきません。

具体的には、保存したソースコード（例. list10-1.c）をコンパイルするために、

```
C:\(list10-1.cのある場所)>cl list10-1.c　　enter
```

とすると、

> 'cl' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。

と表示が出てきます。

ちなみに、書籍には

> コンパイルで問題なければ、自動的にリンクも行われます。
>   コンパイル、リンクがともに成功すれば、
>
> ```
> C:\(list10-1.cのある場所)>list10-1　　enter
> ```
>
> のように実行できるでしょう。

と書いています。

**C Source** をコンパイル＆実行する方法を教えてください。

Comment: Manyama さん。「どのような手順が必要とされていた」のか、それで「どこの手順でうまくいかなかったか」を、書籍を持っていない人にもわかるように説明していただくと、直接役に立つ回答が早くつくかもしれません。

Comment: VisualStudioそのものはインストールしましたか？

Comment: タイトルだけでQ&A内容を把握しやすいよう編集しました。また、後から訪問した人にも読みやすくするため、引用・コードブロックなどのマークアップを入れました。マークアップの記法については[Markdownヘルプ](/editing-help)が参考になります。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. スタートボタンからのプログラム一覧の中で`Microsoft Visual Studio nnnn` -> `Visual Studio Tools` から`Visual Studio コマンド プロンプト (nnnn)` （nnnnはバージョン的な年が入ると思って下さい） のようにしてコマンドプロンプトを立ち上げます。これはパスなんかの設定済みのコマンドプロンプトです。素のコマンドプロンプトを使う場合自分でパスを通したり指定したりします。
2. フォルダ名が長くて折り返されたりすると邪魔くさいので`prompt %`などとします。(気にならなければする必要はありません)
3. ファイルをダウンロードしたフォルダに`cd c:\Users\ログインユーザー名\Downloads` などとして移動します。途中まで書いてタブを押すと補完されるのでそれを利用するのが楽です。
4. `cl list10-1.c` の様に実行するとコンパイルして`list10-1.exe`ができます。
5. `list10-1` の様に実行します。 この時にもタブによる補完ができます。

Comment: 環境によって多少違うかもしれません。

Comment: できました！！！
まさに聞きたかった方法です。
3.のcd c:\Users\ログインユーザー名\Downloadsの部分は、コマンドまでファイルを引っ張ってきて、ファイルの名前だけ消す方が、打ち込むより楽な方法かと思います。

Comment: @Manyama 助けになって良かったです。そうですね。あと、エクスプローラーからコピーして持ってきてもいいし、度々同じフォルダで作業する場合、コマンドプロンプトのアイコンをデスクトップにドラッグしてショートカットを作ってアイコンのプロンプトから作業フォルダとして設定するといいかと思います。

Comment: 前のコメントの `アイコンのプロンプト` は `アイコンのプロパティ` の間違い

Answer (score 1):

私の知っている方法ではVisual Studioでコンパイルする場合コマンドプロンプトを利用することはありません。
Visual Studioを起動し
「ファイル」→「新規作成」→「プロジェクト」

「Win32　コンソール　アプリケーション」
適切な名前を入力し決定すると

「Win32　アプリケーション　ウィザード」が表示されます。
次へを選択し
「空のプロジェクト」に「チェック」を入れを作成してください。

「ソリューション　エクスプローラー」から作成した名前上で「右クリック」します
「追加」→「既存の項目」でダウンロードしたファイルを開いてください。

実行は、
「ビルド」→「デバッグ無しで開始」で実行可能です.

「デバッグ開始」でも実行可能ですが、すぐに閉じてしまうためデバッグ無しで開始してください。
すぐに閉じないようにするには最後の行に文字列の入力を必要とする様にプログラムを書き換えるか、「ブレークポイント」を設定してください。

**しかし、その方法ではその都度プロジェクトを作成ので面倒なので、書籍毎にプロジェクトで管理する方法があります。**
「ソリューション　エクスプローラー」上に表示されている
「フォルダとファイルのアイコン」（カーソルを乗せると「全てのファイルの表示」と表示されます。）
をクリックして

「ソリューション　エクスプローラー」から作成した名前上で「右クリック」し
「エクスプローラーでフォルダを開く」をクリックし、ダウンロードしたファイルを移動又はコピーします。

入力したファイルは禁止マークが表示されていると思います。
実行したいファイルの禁止マークを「右クリック」で「プロジェクトに含める」と実行可能です。
その時、複数のファイルを選択してしまい、メイン関数が0か2つ以上になってしまった場合はそれ相応のエラーが出ます。

Comment: 確認になりますが、「ソリューション　エクスプローラー」から作成した名前上で「右クリック」し、「追加」→「既存項目」でダウンロードしたファイルを開くと「ソースファイル」に追加されるのでしようか？

Comment: はい、そうです。この時複数のファイルを選択してしまうとエラーとなりますので注意してください。正確には「既存の項目」でした。このことは修正します。

Comment: プリコンパイル ヘッダー ファイルが旧バージョンのコンパイラで作成されています。また、C++ のプリコンパイル済みヘッダー ファイルを C で使用しています (その逆も考えられます)。 
というエラーが出ました。
ちなみに、追加前からあったソースファイル、ヘッダーファイルはそのまま置いていて良かったのでしょうか？

Comment: からのプロジェクトを作成してください。から「空のプロジェクト」に「チェック」を入れを作成してください。へ変更しました。サンプルプログラムの実行確認磯のような方法があることは知りませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

（これは回答ではなくオフトピックな参考情報として）

最近はWeb上でC言語ソースコードのコンパイル＆実行ができる、オンライン・コンパイラ・サービスが充実しています。手元マシンにわざわざ開発環境をいれなくても、Internet接続環境とWebブラウザさえあればプログラムを動かすことができます。

図形描画をさせるようなGUIプログラミングや、ファイル読み書きなどのI/O処理には対応していませんが、コンソールに文字を出力して、サンプルコードの動作確認を行う程度ならば十分実用的かと思います。

- http://melpon.org/wandbox/
- http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php
- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: 同感です。書籍の短いサンプルを実行するぐらいであれば、オンライン IDE の方が迷いが少なくて、学びやすいとも考えます。