# C++のソースコードをVisual Studio Expressを利用してコンパイル・実行したい

Tags: c++, visual-studio

アルゴリズムとデータ構造という書籍を買い、下記よりC/C++のソースコードをダウンロードしました。  
http://www.sbcr.jp/books/img/takarabako/

以前した質問（[CのソースコードをVisual Studio Expressを利用してコンパイル・実行したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2981/c%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%92visual-studio-express%E3%82%92%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%91%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB-%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)）の回答と同様に、

> cl list2-6.cpp enter

とすると、

> /out:list2-6.exe
>   list2-6.obj
>   LINK : fatal error LNK1561: エントリー ポイントを定義しなければなりません。

という表示が出てきて上手くコンパイルできません。
どこで問題が生じているか教えていただけないでしょうか？
ちなみに list2-6.cpp は以下のようなコードです。

```
// ＜C++版蔵書検索＞
// ※インクルードファイルやmain()関数はC言語版と同じ

// 蔵書クラス
class CBook
{
public:
    char *title;
    char *author;
    int bookID;
    int available;      /* 貸し出し中なら0，そうでなければ1 */

    // 比較演算子のオーバロード
    // sortbook()のなかでCBookどうしを比較
    bool operator<(CBook&book)
    {
        return bookID<book.bookID;
    }
    bool operator>(CBook&book)
    {
        return bookID>book.bookID;
    }
    // int型へのキャストをオーバロード
    // searchbook()のなかでkeyとbookIDを比較
    operator int()
    {
        return bookID;
    }
};

#define N 5

CBook*bookarray[N];     /* 蔵書データのポインタの配列 */

/* 蔵書のデータを初期化する */
void initdata()
{
    int n;

    for(n=0;n<N;++n)
        bookarray[n]=new CBook;

    bookarray[0]->title="book0";
    bookarray[1]->title="book1";
    bookarray[2]->title="book2";
    bookarray[3]->title="book3";
    bookarray[4]->title="book4";

    bookarray[0]->author="author0";
    bookarray[1]->author="author1";
    bookarray[2]->author="author2";
    bookarray[3]->author="author3";
    bookarray[4]->author="author4";

    bookarray[0]->bookID=1000;
    bookarray[1]->bookID=502;
    bookarray[2]->bookID=731;
    bookarray[3]->bookID=628;
    bookarray[4]->bookID=1;

    bookarray[0]->available=1;
    bookarray[1]->available=0;
    bookarray[2]->available=0;
    bookarray[3]->available=1;
    bookarray[4]->available=1;
}

/* 蔵書データのメモリを解放 */
void cleanupdata()
{
    int n;
    for(n=0;n<N;++n)
        delete bookarray[n];
}

/* 本のデータをbookIDの順に昇順でクイックソートする */
void sortbook(int bottom,int top)
{
    int lower,upper;
    CBook *div,*temp;

    if(bottom>=top)
        return;

    div=bookarray[bottom];  /* 適当な基準値を選択 */
    for(lower=bottom,upper=top;lower<upper;)
    {
        // オブジェクトの大小を直接比較
        while(*bookarray[lower]<*div)
            ++lower;
        while(*bookarray[upper]>*div)
            --upper;
        if(lower<upper)
        {
            /* データ（へのポインタ）の順番を入れ替える */
            temp=bookarray[lower];
            bookarray[lower]=bookarray[upper];
            bookarray[upper]=temp;
            ++lower;
            --upper;
        }
    }
    sortbook(bottom,upper);
    sortbook(upper+1,top);
}

/* booksのなかからbookIDがkeyと一致するデータをバイナリサーチで
    検索して，その添え字を返す。見つからなければ-1を返す */
int searchbook(CBook *books[],int size,int key)
{
    int left,mid,right;

    left=0;
    right=size;
    while(left<right)
    {
        mid=(left+right)/2;
        if(*books[mid]<key)     // CBookのbookIDとkey を比較
            left=mid+1;
        else
            right=mid;
    }
    if(*books[left]==key)       // 同上
        return left;

    return -1;      /* 見つからなかった場合 */
}
```

（追記）

```
// ＜C++版蔵書検索＞
// ※インクルードファイルやmain()関数はC言語版と同じ
```

とあるように、この部分のコードが抜けていたのが原因でした。

Comment: 書籍を購入していない人が実行できないようにmain関数を用意していない場合や意図的に関数名を変えたりバグを挿入しているものがあるのでよく書籍と比較してください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C++ Source をコンパイル＆実行する方法を教えてください。

とのことですが、main()関数が見当たりません。何を実行したいとお考えなのでしょうか？